# Make chrome app windows be always on top

Tags: google-chrome, window-manager

Simply put: Is there any way to make [chrome app windows](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window) have the always on top button when right clicking them?

I am using xubuntu 14.04, and google-chrome dev. Selecting 'use system title bar and borders' just makes the sub window not have a title bar, and the default chrome title bar doesn't have the option.

I'm also not 100% sure that it is the chrome app window linked - it's just a live-feed kind of dialog launched by a javascript function on the web page.

Answer (score 30):

Just focus chrome app window and type `Alt+Space` to open a window menu options and select `Always on top`

Comment: This worked beautifully on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Best answer never ever

Comment: thank you berry much!!

Comment: alt+space does nothing for me on ubuntu 22

Answer (score 11):

I think it is a two step process. 1) Make chrome not full screen and then click use system title bar and borders. 2) On the top part of the bar that was just amended with your last option change (the part above the tabs) right click and select always on top.

Comment: Upon further inspection, you're right. It looks like the app window needed to be reopened for it to work properly. Once it was reopened (with system bars on) it worked just fine

Comment: Wait, no it doesn't work. Now all chrome windows are 'always on top' which is not the desired behavior

Comment: @Musher That was useful to me. Now, I use Firefox for what I want to be at the bottom and Chrome for what I want to be on the top.

Answer (score 0):

You can also:

- ensure Chrome window is not maximized (nor full-screen)
- right-click on Chrome title bar
- click "***Use system title bar and borders***" (to activate)
- right-click on the system title bar
- click "***Always on Top***"
- right-click on Chrome title bar
- click "***Use system title bar and borders***" (to deactivate)